# T-SQL - query filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

table1:

```
Id          Customer No_
7044900804  Z0172132
7044900804  Z0194585
7044907735  Z0172222
7044907735  Z0172222
7044910337  Z0172216
7044911903  Z0117392
```

I would like to get only the values with the **same Id AND different Customer No_** from table1.

```
Id          Customer No_
7044900804  Z0172132
7044900804  Z0194585
```

I've already tried to use query for finding duplicates, but it won't filter values with the **same Id AND same Customer No_** from table1.

```
SELECT  Id
      , [Customer No_]
  FROM table1
GROUP BY Id, [Customer No_]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Could you help me with **T-SQL** query solution?
Thanks for all the advices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Id IN
(
    SELECT  Id
      FROM table1
    GROUP BY Id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Customer No_]) > 1
)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e92fe/1)

Comment: This works great. Fast and simple. I've just slightly edited the query and used it.

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM table1 WHERE Id IN
(
    SELECT  Id
      FROM table1
    GROUP BY Id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Customer No_]) > 1
)`

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is just to join the table together twice, where the IDs are joined, but the Customer No_s do not match.

```
select t1.id, t1.[customer No_], t2.[customer No_]
from table1 t1 
inner join table1 t2
on t1.id = t2.id
and t1.[customer No_] != t2.[customer No_]
```

Comment: That is only reasonable if there are no more than two customer No_s for each ID. If there are e.g. three customers for one id you will get six rows of output!

Comment: Thank you for your input. There can be more than two Customer No_s for each ID, so joining two tables like these won't work. But again thanks, very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id, [Customer No_]) C1, 
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY id) C2 
    FROM 
        YourTable
)x WHERE C1<>C2
```

Comment: Execution of this query takes too much time in this case. But thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT ID, [Customer No_]
FROM table1
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM table1
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING count(*) > 1)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e618/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT t1.Id
      ,t1.[Customer No_]
FROM table1 t1
 JOIN (SELECT Id, COUNT(*) as cnt
       FROM table1 
       GROUP BY id)
 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.cnt > 1
```